# nginx proxy caching not working

Tags: nginx, cache

I an proxying to an external JSON api and am trying to cache the proxy responses. To determine if the proxy cache is working I have added

```
add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
```

and always see a `MISS` value.

My nginx config location:

```
location /api/tides {
  proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
  proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
  proxy_cache worldtidecache;
  proxy_set_header Host www.worldtides.info;
  proxy_pass https://example.com/api/$query_string;
  add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
}
```

Prior to that I have `proxy_cache_path` set

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=worldtidecache:100m max_size=1g inactive=48h use_temp_path=off;
```

`www-data` has read/write access to `/var/cache/nginx`

I am assuming that `proxy_buffering` is set to `on` as I don't have any explicit setting for this.

The nginx config is valid. I have tested it with `nginx -c nginx.conf -t`:

```
╰─sudo nginx -c nginx.conf -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

I've tailed both the `error.log` and `access.log` and I don't see anything that would indicate why the caching wouldn't be working.

The headers I get from the proxy response:

```
Server: nginx/1.11.13
Date: Sun, 20 Aug 2017 14:01:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2976
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Cloud-Trace-Context: 38faabaa5ada170536632bb55a0ddf00;o=1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cached: MISS
```

I'm stuck at this point. I don't know what else would be causing nginx to not cache. There isn't any cache busting happening on the requests like a unique query param, the url is consistent on each request. Outside of setting the header to the cache attempt result I don't know of any other way to log what the proxy caching is doing.

Comment: How do the does the response headers look for `https://www.example.com/api/$query_string`? Does `$query_string` possibly include a cache killer?

Answer (score 5):

Twitter to the rescue: https://twitter.com/btucker/status/899309118137057286

```
proxy_cache_valid any 48h;
```

Comment: I don't know why cache works on other nginx, but in my last project I had to add this proxy_cache_valid and started to cache. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Second solution since @bcardarella's didn't work for me

Add `proxy_buffering on;` to your location block

Source: https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/issues/800#issuecomment-383901151